# In C# VSIX, How to get current file name along with its relative path which is currently being editing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, extensibility

I am working on a VSIX project, where I want to get the current file name and path (relative to the project) which is being edited in the VS IDE (or in an experimental window)? How can I do that?

I tried following code:

```
var currentDocInfo = this._textDocumentFactoryService.TryGetTextDocument(this.view.TextBuffer, out this.TextDocument);            

if (currentDocInfo)
{
    string test = this.TextDocument.FilePath;
    MessageBox.Show(test);
}
else
{
    //MessageBox.Show("Nothingg!");
}
```

This code is returning absolute path of currently opened file. And I need to get path relative to the current project/solution. If I am able to get even the name of solution, I will find the relative path of the project.

If I add code: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);`
It will return the path details of my TextAdornment class (a class, managing the editor tasks by getting installed with my whole plugin, Here I am writing dte.ActiveDocument.FullName; code). But I want file details of the file which is opened in my experimental window.

Comment: you asked and answered and deleted the same question 3 hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716129/in-c-sharp-vsix-how-to-get-current-file-name-along-with-its-path-which-is-curre what's going on?

Comment: That question was deleted eventually, I needed to do some changes with that question. I need to get a relative path from the solution to the currently opened file. The answer I marked was not getting me the relative path. I am also searching to get the solution/project name, If I get that, I will be able to perform string operations to get the relative path.

Comment: What version of .net are you using?

Comment: @Train .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the file name of the current open text editor in your experimental window

`DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
 string docName = dte.ActiveDocument.Name;`

**EDIT**

Example for a menu button, returns the current file name of the open document in the experimental visual studio instance, if the menu button is clicked

```
private void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// Get Open Documents
        string docName = GetActiveTextEditor();
        if (docName == null) return;

    }

internal static string GetActiveTextEditor()
    {
        DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE;
        string docName = dte.ActiveDocument.Name;
        return docName;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to write this code again and again in an experimental window. I want my plugin to do that. How can I put this code in my plugin code so that I get the file name of the currently open text editor in my experimental window?

Comment: You don't write this code to the experimental window but into the plugin. For example: You create a menu button you get an private void Execute(object sender, EvenArgs e) and will add this code above into the Execute function.

Comment: Then It will return the Name or Path of the class where `Execute(object sender, EvenArgs e)` method is present.

Comment: Can you please edit your code above? For me my code works perfectly and gives me the file name of my experimental window

Answer (score 2):

The current file name and path: `dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;`

Solution directory: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);`

Comment: This solution will return the path details of my current TextAdornment class (a class in my plugin where I am writing ```dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;``` this code). But I want file details of the file which is opened in my experimental window.